# Apply a condition using ngFor and ngIf in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi There I have been trying to filter an array with some success using ngIF and ngFor.

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items"> <div *ngIf="(item.data.type == 1)"> {{item.data.name}} </div> </button>
```

This code does only show buttons with name in it for data that has type=1 but it also create empty buttons for each data entry that doesn't have type=1, I can't figure out how to get rid of empty buttons. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I would flip-flop your `button` and `div`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button *ngIf="(item.data.type == 1)">{{item.data.name}}</button>
</div>
```

This way only buttons get created for valid items.

If `<div>`'s aren't desirable use `<ng-container>` instead.

Though not advisable due to performance reasons, you can also use a function in your component:

```
<button *ngFor="let item of filterItemsOfType('1')">{{item.data.name}}</button>
```

Where your component has a function:

```
filterItemsOfType(type){
    return this.items.filter(x => x.data.type == type);
}
```

While this works, it is not recommended and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Flip-flopping the div worked really well :) Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use *ngFor  for creating table headers. This is my code   <th *ngFor="let m of values"> <span *ngIf="m == 'Time'">{{m}}</span><span *ngIf="m == 'Date'">{{m}}</span></th>. When *ngIf doesn't satisfies either of the condition mentioned in span, still a <th> is getting creating(logically that is correct), which is empty but takes some width in the UI. I don't want it to create a th when condition doesn't satisfies.

Comment: @Vasanth try putting the ngFor on a parent `<ng-container></ng-container>` element.  That way a `th` isn't rendered for every item.  And change your `span`s to be the `th`s.

Comment: solution 2 i.e. making a function works well for option list of dropdown... thanks :)

Comment: Flip-Flopping would still create empty divs. Using the method is so far the best in my opinion

Comment: there is a lot of articles about using function in templates and how bad is this pattern bad. Please avoid them. [ref](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Answer (score 33):

You can create your own pipe. That is better solution.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'somepipe',
})
export class SomePipe {

    transform(objects: any[]): any[] {
        if(objects) {
            return objects.filter(object => {
                return object.data.type === 1;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

and use it in html in this way:

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items | somepipe"> <div> {{item.data.name}} </div> </button>
```

Comment: I like this answer - for anyone reading don't forget to put the name of your pipe class into your module declarations.

Comment: A neat solution

Comment: Also Add your pipe declaration in app.module.ts and implements PipeTransform on the Pipe class.

Comment: Is this okay from the performance perspective? While method way is not performant, this looks like the method has been moved into pipe.

Answer (score 7):

`<button *ngFor="let item of getItems()">...</button>`

```
getItems() {
  return this.items.filter((item) => item.data.type === 1);
}
```

where `this.items` is your array of items somewhere above this function.

Check this out

Comment: I'm not sure, if using function returned list is good solution. That method will be called every time when html be rendering

Comment: @JaroslawK. even worse, function (also getter) is called so often that you can have troubles with performance. [ref](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)