# Angular 4 populate the dropdown only matched values

Tags: angular

I want to access array inside objects which is coming from my json file to populate my dropdown values and want to show values on second dropdown only  from previous selected dropdown.

here is my ts:

```
 companySites = false;
  siteSelected = false;
  alldata: any = [];
getCustomerData() {
    this.maintenanceServices.getAllCustomers().subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          this.alldata = data;
          console.log(this.alldata);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  onCustomerChange(): void {
    this.companySites = true;
  }

  onSitecChange(): void {
    this.siteSelected = true;
  }
```

.html:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
      <div>
        <p>Select a company</p>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Company" (selectionChange)="onCustomerChange($event)" value="company">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let company of alldata">
              {{ company.customer.customerName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="companySites">
      <div>
        <p>Select site</p>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Sites" (selectionChange)="onSitecChange($event)" value="site">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let site of alldata.sites; index as i">
              {{ site.buildingName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

and json:

```
"customer": {
"customerName": "ABC",
"customerAddress": "NYC",
"BillingAddress": "ABC",
"ProductInstallation": "drive A",
"sites": [
{
"_id": "5c5be1f2b73bc81dd404ac00",
"buildingName": "Main Building",
"requestDate": "12/02/2019",
"buildingAddress": "123 Street",
"numberofDrives": "3"
},
{
"_id": "5c5be1f2b73bc81dd404abff",
"buildingName": "second Building",
"requestDate": "12/02/2019",
"buildingAddress": "123 Street",
"numberofDrives": "2"
}
]
},
"_id": "5c5be1f2b73bc81dd404abfe",
```

now my json has hundreds of customers with multiple sites. I want to select company and then on second dropdown I want to show sites for selected sites

I have tried:

Object.values but that didn't work either

Comment: [See here how to render using condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931735/apply-a-condition-using-ngfor-and-ngif-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is use the first dropdown to filter the list of objects and display the second dropdown only when a value has been selected by the user, this is done through `*ngIf` and the corresponding sites are shown for the same, please refer the below stackblitz.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <div>
            <p>Select a company</p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Company" [(value)]="company">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let company of alldata" [value]="company.customer">
                        {{ company.customer.customerName }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="company">
        <div>
            <p>Select site</p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Sites" [(value)]="site">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let site of company.sites; index as i" [value]="site">
                        {{ site.buildingName }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    <div>{{site | json}}</div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

<kbd>**StackBlitz**</kbd>

Comment: @MuhammadAli does this answer solve your question, can it be closed?

Answer (score 0):

just use `*ngIf` for that

```
      <mat-select placeholder="Sites" (selectionChange)="onSitecChange($event)" value="site">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let site of alldata.sites; index as i">
           <mat-option *ngIf="whatever site should be">
              {{ site.buildingName }}
           </mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by *whatever site should be*

Comment: put there condition that will decide if gives site should be rendered or not. That is simple IF statement.

Comment: @MuhammadAli this is the best that can be explained with the give json data. give details of alldata to give further info

Comment: alldata: any = []; is just an array to append values from data coming from json... you can check my ts file

Comment: @Antoniossss can you please update your answer? i still dont understand and I tried to use *ngIf="sites.buildingName" but it didnt work either

Comment: Create stackblitz for that as your datamodel shown is a mess IMHO. https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Why would you even want to do that `*ngIf="sites.buildingName"` Do you know what `*igIf` is for and how it works?