# How to get first active image in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I get first active image in ionic from restful service?

**Explanation:** I am trying to create **Infinite Scrolling Photo** in ionic and I need first image to have a **class="first"**. Using `let i = index` how can I achieve this?

What I tried:

```
<div class="photobanner" *ngFor="let slideImage of items; let i = index">
      <img class="first" src='{{slideImage[i].img}}' />
      <img src='{{slideImage[i+1].img}}'>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css. You select the first img child of the div photobanner

```
.photobanner > img:first-child {
  //do what you want
}
```

Other solution, you can find here how to add condition in ngFor.
[stackoverflow.com/questions/42931735/apply-a-condition-using-ngfor-and-ngif-in-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931735/apply-a-condition-using-ngfor-and-ngif-in-angular-2)